# ERROR The following nodes should be connected but aren't: * /move_base->/move_base

Tags: yaml, ros, gazebo-simu

When I tried the launch my navigation.launch, the robot comes in the desired direction in rviz, but when I use 2d pose estimate, it turns the robot 90 degrees to the left according to what it should be. Later, when I give a target point with 2d nav goal, it cannot follow the path and moves to other directions by sliding to the left. I looked for errors using roswtf and got the following nodes connection error. I don't know where is the problem. How can I fix the footprints?

**roswtf output**

[image: roswtf]

**navigation.launch**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>
  <!-- Arguments -->
  <arg name="model" default="$(find project_ws)/urdf/wheel.urdf"/>
  <arg name="map_file" default="$(find project_ws)/gazebo_map/map.yaml"/>
  <arg name="open_rviz" default="true"/>
  <arg name="move_forward_only" default="false"/>
  <arg name="paused" default="false"/>
  <arg name="use_sim_time" default="true"/>
  <arg name="gui" default="true"/>
  <arg name="headless" default="false"/>
  <arg name="debug" default="false"/>
  <arg name="x" default="1.0"/>
  <arg name="y" default="-5.0"/>
  <arg name="z" default="1.0"/>
  <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
    <arg name="world_name" value="$(find turtlebot3_gazebo)/worlds/turtlebot3_house.world"/>
    <arg name="debug" value="$(arg debug)" />
    <arg name="gui" value="$(arg gui)" />
    <arg name="paused" value="$(arg paused)"/>
    <arg name="use_sim_time" value="$(arg use_sim_time)"/>
    <!--arg name="world_name" value="world/mud.world"/-->
    <arg name="headless" value="$(arg headless)"/>
    </include>

  <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro $(arg model)" />
  <node name="urdf_spawner" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model"
        args="-z 1.0 -unpause -urdf -model robot -param robot_description -x $(arg x) -y $(arg y) -z $(arg z)"  respawn="false" output="screen" />
  <node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher"
    respawn="false" output="screen">
  </node>
  <node name="joint_state_publisher" pkg="joint_state_publisher" type="joint_state_publisher">
  </node>

  
 


  <!-- Map server -->
  <node pkg="map_server" name="map_server" type="map_server" args="$(arg map_file)"/>

  <!-- AMCL -->
  <include file="$(find project_ws)/launch/amcl.launch"/>

  <!-- move_base -->
  <include file="$(find project_ws)/launch/move_base.launch">
    <arg name="model" value="$(arg model)" />
    <arg name="move_forward_only" value="$(arg move_forward_only)"/>
  </include>

  <!-- rviz -->
  <group if="$(arg open_rviz)"> 
    <node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" name="rviz" required="true"
          args="-d $(find project_ws)/rviz/navigation.rviz"/>
  </group>
</launch>
```

**move_base.launch**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>
  <!-- Arguments -->
  <arg name="model" default="$(find project_ws)/urdf/wheel.urdf"/>
  <arg name="cmd_vel_topic" default="/vehiclediffdrive/cmd_vel" />
  <arg name="odom_topic" default="/vehiclediffdrive/odom" />
  <arg name="move_forward_only" default="false"/>

  <!-- move_base -->
  <node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base" output="screen">
    <param name="base_local_planner" value="dwa_local_planner/DWAPlannerROS" />
    <rosparam file="$(find project_ws)/param/costmap_common_params_burger.yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find project_ws)/param/costmap_common_params_burger.yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find project_ws)/param/local_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find project_ws)/param/global_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find project_ws)/param/move_base_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find project_ws)/param/dwa_local_planner_params_burger.yaml" command="load" />
    <remap from="cmd_vel" to="$(arg cmd_vel_topic)"/>
    <remap from="odom" to="$(arg odom_topic)"/>
    <param name="DWAPlannerROS/min_vel_x" value="0.0" if="$(arg move_forward_only)" />
  </node>
</launch>
```

**costmap_common_params.yaml**

```
obstacle_range: 3.0
raytrace_range: 3.5

footprint: [[-0.105, -0.105], [-0.105, 0.105], [0.041, 0.105], [0.041, -0.105]]
#robot_radius: 0.105

inflation_radius: 1.0
cost_scaling_factor: 3.0

map_type: costmap
observation_sources: vehiclediffdrive/laser/scan
vehiclediffdrive/laser/scan: {sensor_frame: laser_scan, data_type: LaserScan, topic: vehiclediffdrive/laser/scan, marking: true, clearing: true}
```

**local_costmap_params.yaml**

```
local_costmap:
  global_frame: odom
  robot_base_frame: base_link

  update_frequency: 10.0
  publish_frequency: 10.0
  transform_tolerance: 0.5  

  static_map: false  
  rolling_window: true
  width: 3
  height: 3
  resolution: 0.05
```

**global_costmap_params.yaml**

```
global_costmap:
  global_frame: map
  robot_base_frame: base_link

  update_frequency: 10.0
  publish_frequency: 10.0
  transform_tolerance: 0.5

  static_map: true
```

**move_base_params.yaml**

```
shutdown_costmaps: false
controller_frequency: 10.0
planner_patience: 5.0
controller_patience: 15.0
conservative_reset_dist: 3.0
planner_frequency: 5.0
oscillation_timeout: 10.0
oscillation_distance: 0.2
```

**base_local_planner_params.yaml**

```
TrajectoryPlannerROS:

# Robot Configuration Parameters
  max_vel_x: 0.10
  min_vel_x: 0.08

  max_vel_theta:  1.0
  min_vel_theta: -1.0
  min_in_place_vel_theta: 1.0

  acc_lim_x: 1.0
  acc_lim_y: 0.0
  acc_lim_theta: 0.6

# Goal Tolerance Parameters
  xy_goal_tolerance: 0.10
  yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.05

# Differential-drive robot configuration
  holonomic_robot: true

# Forward Simulation Parameters
  sim_time: 0.8
  vx_samples: 18
  vtheta_samples: 20
  sim_granularity: 0.05
```

**dwa_local_planner_params.yaml**

```
DWAPlannerROS:

# Robot Configuration Parameters
  max_vel_x: 0.1
  min_vel_x: -0.1

  max_vel_y: 0.1
  min_vel_y: -0.1

# The velocity when robot is moving in a straight line
  max_vel_trans:  0.22
  min_vel_trans:  0.11

  max_vel_theta: 2.75
  min_vel_theta: 1.37

  acc_lim_x: 2.5
  acc_lim_y: 2.5
  acc_lim_theta: 3.2 

# Goal Tolerance Parametes
  xy_goal_tolerance: 0.05
  yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.17
  latch_xy_goal_tolerance: false

# Forward Simulation Parameters
  sim_time: 2.0
  vx_samples: 20
  vy_samples: 0
  vth_samples: 40
  controller_frequency: 10.0

# Trajectory Scoring Parameters
  path_distance_bias: 16.0
  goal_distance_bias: 20.0
  occdist_scale: 0.02
  forward_point_distance: 0.325
  stop_time_buffer: 0.2
  scaling_speed: 0.25
  max_scaling_factor: 0.2

# Oscillation Prevention Parameters
  oscillation_reset_dist: 0.05

# Debugging
  publish_traj_pc : true
  publish_cost_grid_pc: true
```